# Using enumerated with ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to know about syntax of using enumerated with `ForEach`. I am using a `customID`.

Here is my code:

```
ForEach(arrayNew.enumerated(), id:\.customID) { (index, item) in

}
```

Update:

```
ForEach(Array(arrayNew.enumerated()), id:\.element.customID) { (index, item) in
    Text(String(index) + item)  
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62384275/12299030? Or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59863409/12299030?

Comment: thanks a lot, I do not understand why I should put my arrayNew in another Array? why? also please see my update for any improvement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume we have an `Array` of objects of type `Item`:

```
struct Item {
    let customID: Int
    let value: String
}

let arrayNew = [
    Item(customID: 1, value: "1"),
    Item(customID: 23, value: "12"),
    Item(customID: 2, value: "32")
]
```

Now, if we want to access both `offset` *and* `item` from the array, we need to use `enumerated()`:

```
arrayNew.enumerated()
```

However, it returns an `EnumeratedSequence` (and **not** an `Array`):

```
@inlinable public func enumerated() -> EnumeratedSequence<Array<Element>>
```

If we take a look at the signature of `ForEach`, we can see that it expects `RandomAccessCollection`:

```
public struct ForEach<Data, ID, Content> where Data : RandomAccessCollection, ID : Hashable
```

The problem here is that `EnumeratedSequence` doesn't conform to `RandomAccessCollection`.

But `Array` *does* - we just need to *convert* the result of `enumerated()` *back* to an `Array`:

```
Array(arrayNew.enumerated())
```

Now, we can use it directly in the `ForEach`:

```
ForEach(Array(arrayNew.enumerated()), id: \.element.customID) { offset, item in
    Text("\(offset) \(item.customID) \(item.value)")
}
```

Comment: That is good to understand why I have to use Array() but why we do not need it here: ** for (index, item) in <#T##items: Any...##Any#>.enumerated() {
    
    <#T##items: Any...##Any#>
    
} **

Comment: @mimi This is because `for-in` loop requires conformance to `Sequence` - which applies to both `Array` and `EnumeratedSequence`. The *standard* `for-in` loop is completely different from SwiftUI `ForEach`.

Comment: so helpful, thanks again! My last but least question, when we use enumerated() in our codes, does put side effect in our app? is it make it expensive to run codes with enumerated method? I mean if I just use my codes without enumerated is it faster in run time?

Comment: @mimi As far as I know, you shouldn't see any difference.