# Tried to make rows of 3-column deletable buttons, but something doesn't work here

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I tried to make multiple rows of 3 columns buttons in a VStack. It worked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62373658/how-to-align-the-an-image-on-top-of-a-button-in-swiftui), after I rewrote the solution to make the buttons to appear in a row of 3 columns, it didnt work anymore - when I click the 'Delete Button', the additional trash image will not appear  on each button. Anything goes wrong here?

```
class SomeData: ObservableObject{
    @Published var buttonObjects: [ButtonObject] = [ButtonObject(name: "tag1", isSelected: false),
                                                   ButtonObject(name: "tag2", isSelected: false), ButtonObject(name: "tag3", isSelected: false), ButtonObject(name: "tag4", isSelected: false)]
    }

struct someData3: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var mode
    @ObservedObject var someData = SomeData()
    @State var newButtonTitle = ""
    @State var isEdit = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
//            List{ // VStack
                VStack{
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            ForEach(0..<someData.buttonObjects.count/3+1) { row in // create number of rows
                                HStack{
                                    ForEach(0..<3) { column in // create 3 columns
                                        self.makeView(row: row, column: column)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }



                    HStack{
                        TextField("Enter new button name", text: $newButtonTitle){
                            let newObject = ButtonObject(name: self.newButtonTitle, isSelected: false)
                            self.someData.buttonObjects.append(newObject)
                            self.newButtonTitle = ""
                        }
                    }

                    Spacer()

                    HStack{
                        Text("isEdit is ")
                        Text(String(self.isEdit))
                        }
                }
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {self.isEdit.toggle()}){Text("Delete Button")},
                                 trailing: EditButton())


                }




    }


    func makeView(row: Int, column: Int) -> some View{
        let ind = row * 3 + column
        return Group{
            if ind<self.someData.buttonObjects.count {
                   Button(action: {
                    self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].isSelected = !self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].isSelected
                    print("Button pressed! buttonKeyName is: \(self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].name) Index is \(ind)")
                    print("bool is \(self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].isSelected)")

                   }) {

                    Text(self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].name)

                   }
                   .buttonStyle(GradientBackgroundStyle(isTapped: self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].isSelected))
                    .overlay(Group {
                         if self.isEdit {
                             ZStack {
                                 Button(action: {self.deleteItem(ind: ind)}) {
                                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                                         .foregroundColor(.red).font(.title)
                                 }.padding(.trailing, 40)
                                    .alignmentGuide(.top) { $0[.bottom] }
                             }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing) //topTrailing

                            }
                        }
                    )
                   .padding(.bottom, 20)


            }
            else{
                EmptyView()

            }
        }

    }


    func deleteItem(ind: Int) {
        let name = someData.buttonObjects[ind].name
        print(" deleting ind \(ind), key: \(name)")
        self.someData.buttonObjects.remove(at: ind)
       }


}
```

Comment: @Asperi mind to take a look here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an explicit `.id` at the end of the `ForEach` - since you're using a static `ForEach` you may need to force refresh it.

In your previous post you used a dynamic `ForEach` (with the `id` parameter). That's why it worked.

```
ForEach(0 ..< someData.buttonObjects.count / 3 + 1) { row in // create number of rows
    HStack {
        ForEach(0 ..< 3) { column in // create 3 columns
            self.makeView(row: row, column: column)

        }
    }
}
.id(UUID()) // <- add this line
```

Comment: After adding that line, the trash image shows up, but when you tap it, nothing happens which isn't right.

Comment: This looks like a different question. *when I click the 'Delete Button', the additional trash image will not appear on each button. Anything goes wrong here?* - I think I answered your question.

Comment: For those buttons that are newly created by users, they can be deleted when trash image is hit. But for the default tag ( tag1, tag2, tag3 ) on the first row, nothing happens when you hit the trash image.

Comment: The problem you face may be related with `.alignmentGuide(.top) { $0[.bottom] }`. If you remove this line it will work. But what I tried to say before is that this problem should be posted as *another* question.

Comment: nope, I still wish to retain that line as the trash image should appear slightly at the top of the button. I realised when you add a Spacer() like this:                 VStack{Spacer()VStack(alignment: .leading){...})}, then everything works just as fine. It seems that, without adding Spacer(), something is prohibiting the trash image to be tapped on the first 3 buttons in the first row.

Comment: I understand your problem, however, your question (*trash image will not appear on each button*) have been answered. Currently you're trying to get an answer to another problem. Please post *another* question. I'll try to help you there.

Comment: ok. just made a new post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392177/tried-to-make-rows-of-3-column-deletable-buttons-but-the-first-row-of-the-butto)