# Tried to make rows of 3-column deletable buttons, but the first row of the buttons are not deletable

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

This post is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62389168/tried-to-make-rows-of-3-column-deletable-buttons-but-something-doesnt-work-her). After making rows on 3-column-buttons, when 'Delete Button' is hit, the first 3 buttons are not deletable when the 'trash' image is hit. However, the second row buttons( i.e. tag4) can be deleted. Any idea what went wrong here? All buttons should be deletable.

Here's the code

```
class SomeData: ObservableObject{
    @Published var buttonObjects: [ButtonObject] = [ButtonObject(name: "tag1", isSelected: false),
                                                   ButtonObject(name: "tag2", isSelected: false), ButtonObject(name: "tag3", isSelected: false), ButtonObject(name: "tag4", isSelected: false)]
}

struct someData3: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var mode
    @ObservedObject var someData = SomeData()
    @State var newButtonTitle = ""
    @State var isEdit = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
//            List{ // VStack
                VStack{
//                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){//
                            ForEach(0..<someData.buttonObjects.count/3+1) { row in // create number of rows
                                HStack{
                                    ForEach(0..<3) { column in // create 3 columns
                                            self.makeView(row: row, column: column)
//                                        makeView2(row: row, column: column, someData: self.someData, isEdit: self.$isEdit)
                                    }
                                }
                            }.id(UUID())
                        }



                    HStack{
                        TextField("Enter new button name", text: $newButtonTitle){
                            let newObject = ButtonObject(name: self.newButtonTitle, isSelected: false)
                            self.someData.buttonObjects.append(newObject)
                            self.newButtonTitle = ""
                        }
                    }

                    Spacer()

                    HStack{
                        Text("isEdit is ")
                        Text(String(self.isEdit))
                        }
                }
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {self.isEdit.toggle()}){Text("Delete Button")},
                                 trailing: EditButton())


                }




    }


    func makeView(row: Int, column: Int) -> some View{
        let ind = row * 3 + column
        return Group{
            if ind<self.someData.buttonObjects.count {
                   Button(action: {
                    self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].isSelected = !self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].isSelected
                    print("Button pressed! buttonKeyName is: \(self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].name) Index is \(ind)")
                    print("bool is \(self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].isSelected)")

                   }) {

                    Text(self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].name)

                   }
                   .buttonStyle(GradientBackgroundStyle(isTapped: self.someData.buttonObjects[ind].isSelected))
                    .overlay(Group {
                         if self.isEdit {
                             ZStack {
                                 Button(action: {self.deleteItem(ind: ind)}) {
                                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                                         .foregroundColor(.red).font(.title)
                                 }.padding(.trailing, 3)
                                    .alignmentGuide(.top) { $0[.bottom] }
                             }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing) //topTrailing

                            }
                        }
                    )
                   .padding(.bottom, 20)


            }
            else{
                EmptyView()

            }
        }

    }






    func deleteItem(ind: Int) {
        let name = someData.buttonObjects[ind].name
        print(" deleting ind \(ind), key: \(name)")
        self.someData.buttonObjects.remove(at: ind)
       }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have may occur because your top button's overlay overlaps with the `NavigationView` title bar which will block input for the button.

If you add some background colour to your `VStack` you'll see your top buttons' trash buttons are actually *outside* the VStack:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        ...
    }
    .background(Color.red)
}
```

One of the solutions is to move the trash image closer to the middle of the button by removing this line:

```
.alignmentGuide(.top) { $0[.bottom] }
```

Alternatively you can make sure your trash buttons will not overlap with the `NavigationView` title bar. As an example you can add a small space above your `VStack` to make your trash buttons fit inside:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
            .frame(height: 10)
        VStack {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also get the same result with `.padding`:

```
Button(action: { }) {
    ...
}
.buttonStyle(...)
.overlay(...)
.padding(.top, 20)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I cannot remove this line .alignmentGuide(.top) { $0[.bottom] } as I wish the trash button to appear above the button a little. I guess adding Spacer().frame(height:10) is a good idea!